# Intent to invoke another intent (without followup intents)

Tags: python, webhooks, dialogflow-es

I have an intent called `ContinueIntent` and its event is named `ContinueEvent`.
I also have an intent called `DummyIntent`. I'm using Dialogflow V2.

I want the user to invoke `DummyIntent`. This then links to the webhook which returns a parameter value and then invokes `ContinueIntent`.

Please respond with the python/JSON which should be returned from the webhook. The question then is how do I change my existing webhook and JSON (shown below) to allow me to:

1. Invoke another intent
2. pass through a value

**Current JSON:**

```
{
    "fulfillmentText": text,
    "source": source
}
```

I read somewhere to add (but I don't know where and can't get it to work):

```
CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'sdfghjkl34notreal567890dfghjkl'

ai = apiai.ApiAI(CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN)

req = ai.event_request(apiai.events.Event("ContinueEvent"))

response = req.getResponse().read()
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to change the JSON to the following:

```
"followupEventInput":{  
              "name":"ContinueEvent",
              "parameters":{
                  "param": param_value
                  }
              },
```

Comment: How do I have this solution written in node webhook please?